# menu always on top and horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

i have that trouble - http://pickup.eurocargo.fi/last500.php i need to do top menu what always on top, and the menu width can be 2x more than width of monitor. How is possbile do that top menu with horizontal scrolling?

Here is top menu css:

```
.visibleDiv, #topmenu
{

    position: fixed;
overflow: auto  ;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
   padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

With the overflow tag i get to scrolls, 1 of page and 1 of the menu, i need to combine it to 1. If i use this css without overflow, then i get cutted topmenu.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/lulu3030/3sTWF/

The css :

```
html {
    height: 300%;
}

#menu-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    background: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
}

#menu {
    width: 200%;
}
```

The HTML :

```
<div id="menu-container">
    <div id="menu">My menu here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Some trouble..... Please look result - http://pickup.eurocargo.fi/last500.php . The menu scroll still is

Comment: What troubles ? The background of the menu ? I don't see.

Comment: Please look, the end of the menu cant see. The cut some part of this menu. INV  EX  PL  OUT  MRN cells can see if scroll top scroll. I need to add the crolling to bottom, together with all page

Answer (score 0):

You still need to set background:;

Comment: btw check your with:; on #topmenu you both got px and %

Comment: What i need write to background and what px and % problem?

Comment: well i see you used another solution?

Comment: #topmenu
{

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    text-align: center;
    background: some-hex-of-your-own-choise;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: WTF?  How background color can help to automatize scroll?